# How to match all >< except bold tag

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a regular expression `[&<>]` for matching `<` and `>` in text.

Like `<i>text</i>` - will match <, >, <, >,

But I don't want it to match `<b>` and `</b>`

How can I do this?

Example: `<i>match me</i> <b>don't match me</b> <i>match me</i>`

Will match only `<` and `>` for italic tags

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser or HTML parser library instead of regex? It would probably make your life easier. It's possible to get a quick and dirty solution with regex, but there will always be corner cases you won't be able to squash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!b)>|(?!<b)(?!</b)<
```

[*Demo*](https://regex101.com/r/Vc2nyc/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<!b)>|(?!<b)(?!</b)<
       |                # match either
      >                 # a >,
(?<!b)                  # not preceeded by a b
                     <  # or a <,
        (?!<b)          # not preceeded by a <b
              (?!</b)   # and neither by </b
```

Lookaround assertions typically have to have a fixed length, which is why we need two for the opening angle bracket: one for `<b>`, and one for `</b>`.